# Object is rendering normal in the Preview (Cycles) but black in the Render.

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Notice how the stove handles are black in the render and normal in the preview in the lower right

[image]

Comment: could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5181" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5181/)

Comment: I don't have the same problem when I render, so I don't know what happens to you  :/